# Flutter - Adding arrays to a widget list

Tags: arrays, list, widget

I want to add all the data in the applicants list but it only adds the last data in the array. Sorry I am still new to flutter.

This is my code.

```
List<ApplicantsList> applicants;

Future <void> getApplicantInfo() async {

  AuthService().getRequestorApplicants().then((val) async {    
    for (var i = 0; i < val.data.length; i++) {
      var temp = val.data[i];
      applicants = [
        ApplicantsList(name: temp['parentname'], contact: temp['parentname'], location: temp['location'])
      ];
    }    
  }); 
}
```

This is my ApplicantsList

```
class ApplicantsList {
  String name;
  String contact;
  String location;

  ApplicantsList({this.name, this.contact, this.location});
}
```

This is where I display applicants list.

```
Container(
   child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
   stream: null,
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
   return Container(
       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
       child: ListView(
       shrinkWrap: true,
       scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
       children: <Widget>[
          Column(
             children: applicants.map((e) => _PendingCardDonor(e.name, e.contact, e.location),).toList(),
           ),
          ],
        ));
      }),
   ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized it's because `List` is deprecated. So I just need to add [] like this one. `List<ApplicantsList> applicants = [];`